# Inherits help_text from django.db.models.Field in rest_framework.serializer.Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's consider

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    bar = models.IntegerField(help_text='This is bar')
    baz = models.IntegerField(help_text='This is baz')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=9)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('bar', 'baz')
```

In this example, FooSerializer has two fields:

- **bar**: `serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=9)`
- **baz**: `serializers.IntegerField(label='This is baz')`. The label is automatically inherited from the help_text property.

For documentation purposes, i would like to *inherits* help_text even if i redefine the field. In this case, i have to since i need min/max value for bar. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inherit the options defined in the model fields in your serializer and add some extra options, **you need to use the [`extra_kwargs`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) option.**

You need a define a dictionary `extra_kwargs` in your serializer's `Meta` class. This will allow you to specify arbitrary additional keyword arguments on fields. You will then not need to explicitly declare the field on the serializer.

The keys of the `extra_kwargs` dictionary will be the field names for which you want to add some additional arguments and its value will be a dictionary containing those additional keyword arguments.

## serializers.py

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('bar', 'baz')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'bar': { # add additional arguments for 'bar' field
                'min_value':0, # specify 'min_value' argument 
                'max_value': 9 # specify 'max_value' argument
            }
        }
```

The above approach will add those additional arguments to the model fields apart from inheriting the default arguments specified in the model.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for even though it is less readable. Thanks

Comment: What if I need a custom field class?